# .net core web api returns only clear text, should be based on client capabilities

Tags: c#, routes, .net-core, http-get, asp.net-core-webapi

I am writing a very lightweight web api to present small logfile(s) data.
There is no database involved. And it must be based on Kestral. (optional IIS). The data don't needs to be deleted or edited, its only about viewing of data. And depending on the client request it should result raw data or put html formatting over it so one is able to dive deeper into the logfile, by showing click-able logfilenames (click on a log file and see its content).

I'm quite new to .net core, and so I have my doubts, obviously I do something wrong here, i was trying to make response based upon client capabilities  but its not working out.

Even if In try to enforce HTML coding, i keep getting plain text replies as would be ok for telnet (direct api call) but in Firefox/chrome/Edge, is there something extra I need to do ?.
To get it working as HTML reply in web browsers

So I wrote a  ASP netcore program like :

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: true --> //code collaps ?
namespace Dataview    //this is the file : program.cs
{   
 public class Program
 {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .AddCommandLine(args)
      .Build();

        var hostUrl = configuration["hosturl"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hostUrl)) hostUrl = "http://192.168.10.60:9000";
        string port = hostUrl.Split(":")[2];
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd", "/C netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=\"Http Logger Port\" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport="+port);
        BuildWebHost(args, hostUrl).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args, string hostUrl) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseUrls(hostUrl).UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
 }
}
```

And my value controller program ValuesController.cs looks like:

```
namespace Dataview.Controllers
  {
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
   public class ValuesController : Controller
  {
    const string LogFolder = @"C:\Data\Count";
    String[] result = Directory.GetFiles(LogFolder);

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()//System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Get()  
    {
        var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<html><body>"); //trying to enforce HTML decoration=> doesnt work
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append($"<div><a href='{Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { Action = "", id = i })}'>{Path.GetFileName(result[i])}</div>");
        }

        sb.Append("</body></html>");
        string answer = sb.ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++) result[i] = Path.GetFileName(result[i]);
        return answer;
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(result[id]);
        string answer = "Showing : " + result[id] + "\n" + string.Join('\n', lines);
        return answer;
    }
```

**=== Update ===**

I managed to get a Json result by controler code changes, however the displayed list isnt clickable either (no HTML decoration for that either ) :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    const string LogFolder = @"C:\Data\Count";
    String[] result = Directory.GetFiles(LogFolder);

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()//System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Get()  //IEnumerable<string> 

    {
        List<string> allFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(LogFolder).ToList();
        allFiles.Reverse(); //newest on top
        return Json(allFiles) ;
```

Comment: Try `return Content(answer)`.

Comment: Content as a verb is not recognized , what does it need for namespace ?

Comment: [ControllerBase.Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.content?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_Content_System_String_) should be accessible unless you aren't using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller`?

Comment: i've added it, but still it outputs plain text in a web browser (not even the forced html formatting works) (though i think it shouldnt be enforced).

Comment: Change your return type to `ActionResult`, then try using `Content()`.

Comment: Or better yet, use a view.

Comment: still plain text, .. 
maybe i'd stay with JsonResult, but it seams AllowJsonGet is disalowed these days, so then i need a way to get clickable url's in 'return Json (allfiles).

Comment: Post the raw response your browser is getting in the question.

Comment: the raw response is a plain array string between brackets,alike
[{ "filename":"C:\\Data\\Count\\simon-Choose-2017-12-11 1538.txt","url":"../../Api/values/0"},{"filenmae":"C:\\Data ........   },{... },{..}]

Comment: solved it trough adjusted routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .net core ASP MCV 2.0.x a Json list as retrieved from [HTTPGET] cannot be clicked. Because of a vulnerability of cross site scripting, which was in .net core 1.0

Though one work around it using Routes, and create specific route for web results, and provide a different route for a web API.

ea have a website http://x.x.x.x/Api/valeus
=> for Json interact with GET/PUT

have a website http://x.x.x.x/Web/Welcome
=> for web results, .interact with Views  MVC (razor pages).

Other routes are possible, depending on your route filters
Routes can be based on client capabilities,.. i think but that depends heavily on client browser, creating clear path based routing might be a bit more work but keeps it clear.

PS it might be more easy to use out of the box templates.
But if you cannot use that (like in my case) then i hope above is usefull